# URL path changing after page load with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router, gatsby-plugin

I have a problem where when a site gets loaded, the URL is then changed causing the URL to be incorrect if you then try to share it. The site loads fine otherwise, but then changes to the incorrect URL

For example, the site is located in some sub folders ("en-us/site") on the domain which looks like this if you are on the blog page: `www.example.com/en-us/site/blog/`. So if you go to that URL the page will load fine but after loading the URL in the address bar will change to just be `www.example.com/blog/`

This only became an issue when a dev accidentally updating the dependencies in NPM. I have narrowed it down to being an update to Gatsby. Unfortunately there is way too many possibilities for which version is the culprit, nor how to solve it. We went from Gatsby version **2.4.6** to version **2.30.1** so the issue kicks in somewhere between those.

Does anyone have any hints to what could be causing this URL change?

Our dependency list while it was working looked like the following. The only difference that will cause the issue is an update to the gatsby package. I am unsure which specific version starts the issue as it would take too long to try each and every one, but going to 2.30.1 definitely causes issues.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "gatsby": "^2.20.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.15",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.3.5",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.10",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.2.26",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.31.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "gatsby-disable-404": "^0.2.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-eslint": "^2.0.8",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1"
  },
```

The **siteUrl** in gatsby-config.js is set correctly with `https://www.example.com/en-us/site` as the URL and **assetPrefix** is set to `/en-us/site`.

I have narrowed it down to just an update to the **gatsby** package will cause the issue. Also the issue seems to only be reproduceable on our staging and production servers. I have been unable to repro locally with a local server setup.

We could keep with the old versions but I don't want to risk this issue in case it accidentally happens again (via rogue package-lock file) and would rather just get to the latest version anyway.

Comment: Can you rollback your full dependency list to the working one?

Comment: I can and have done so to get production working, but that doesn't solve the issue for when I do actually want to update.